# How can I use tabhost?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I want to use tabs but it don't work.
Here my .java codes :

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");
        TabSpec tab4 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4");
        TabSpec tab5 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab5");
        tab1.setIndicator("menu").setContent(new Intent(this, tab1.class));
        tab2.setIndicator("language").setContent(new Intent(this,tab2.class ));
        tab3.setIndicator("speaking").setContent(new Intent(this,tab3.class));
        tab4.setIndicator("share").setContent(new Intent(this, tab4.class));
        tab5.setIndicator("winnig").setContent(new Intent(this,tab5.class ));
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);
        tabHost.addTab(tab4); 
        tabHost.addTab(tab5);
```

here my .xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

here is error :

```
> 01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.tasarimprojesi.donem1/com.tasarimprojesi.donem1.user_manual}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: SHow more code please. Did you set a contentview before you did `findviewbyid`? and please post the complete stacktrace, and show us what lines it refers to.

Comment: Post more error stack trace. The one you posted doesn't have any information except NullPointerException.

Comment: this my main class setContentView(R.layout.user_manual); 

THis is tab1.class
package com.tasarimprojesi.donem1;
 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class tab1 extends Activity {
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
  textView.setText("İkinci Tab");
  setContentView(textView);
 } 
}

Comment: 01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)

Comment: 01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: 01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at

Comment: 01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:238)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at com.tasarimprojesi.donem1.user_manual.onCreate(user_manual.java:69)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: 01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-24 23:48:47.048: E/AndroidRuntime(19837):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend TabActivity, are you?

And then

```
TabHost host = getTabHost();
```